# Made one instance of a class equal to another. – How to cancel that?

Tags: c#

I have:

```
instance1 = instance2;
```

how do I disconnect them from one another, so that altering one will not affect the other?

EDIT: I want them referencing the same object (so I can’t clone), and later – not. But I still want both instances of the class – so I can’t ‘null’ them.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
myclass a = new myclass();
a.integer = 1;

myclass b = new myclass();
b.integer = 2;

a = b;
//All changes to one will affect the other, Which is what I want.



//<More lines of the program>



//Now I want 'a' to point to something else than 'b'. and I’m missing the code
//so that the next line will not affect 'b'.
a.integer = 1;

Text = b.integer.ToString();
//I need b.integer to still be = 2, it’s not.
```

With:

```
class myclass
{
    public int integer;
}
```

EDIT:

*This* is *the* answer:
@ispiro but when you say a.integer = 1 you aren't changing the pointer, you are following the pointer and changing the value at the end of it. – Davy8

I had thought that changing both ‘a’ and ‘a.integer’ would be the same in the sense that changing them would either change pointer-‘a’ or won’t. But in fact: the first does, the second doesn’t.

Thanks everyone.

So in the example above, if I add:

```
a = c;// where c is another instance of 'myclass'.
```

It **will** change ‘a’ to point somewhere else than ‘b’.
But:

```
a.integer = 1;
```

did not.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want two instances with the same information clone the object instead of assigning it.

Comment: I think you're wanting to clone objects instead of refer to the exact same instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c

Comment: These variables aren't "connected" they are just pointing to the same thing. Imagine you were pointing a tree with both your left and right hands. If you stop pointing at the tree with the left hand, you have in no way affected the tree or your right hand.

Comment: @chris lively See edit to question.

Comment: What do you mean by "so that setting one will not affect the other"? What does "setting" mean in the context of your question?

Comment: Would you be able to first set them to the same reference and then when you want them to point to different references clone instance1 setting instance2 to refer to the new instance?  It really is unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can you show us more code, or why you need this? We're having a hard time understanding what you're saying.

Comment: @ JohnFx Means: instance2 = someValue; //not changing instance1

Comment: Can you show a code sample of what "setting" means. Are you saying that changing the object referenced by instance1 won't affect the object referenced by instance2? If so, that is impossible under the constraints you have laid out because they are the same object.

Comment: @ispiro "instance2 = someValue; //not changing instance1"  Are making a statement that that line doesn't change `instance`?  Or are you saying you don't want it to change `instance1`, because it won't change the instance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask with the edit.  Is that what you want to happen or is that something you don't want to happen?

Comment: @Davy8 - it does. try the code in the new edit in the question.

Comment: @Davy8 - I don't. I want to get "2".

Comment: I still don't understand what you actually want to happen.  You're giving a lot of code and not always being clear about stating both what actually happens and what you expect/want to happen.

Comment: @ispiro instance2 = someValue;  will NOT change instance1. You need to get that idea out of your head. It is confusing you.

Comment: Re: your update: If it hurts when you say "a = b;" then don't say that. Why are you assigning "a" to refer to the same object as "b" if you don't want it to refer to the same object?

Comment: @JohnFx So how come the code above returns “1”?

Comment: @Eric This is just an example, of course. I **do** want both pointers to point to the same object. I just want to change this fact later.

Comment: @ispiro too long to fit in a comment. Editing it into my answer.

Comment: @ispiro: So what is stopping you from changing it? You made "a" refer to one object, then you made it refer to another object. If you want to make it refer to a third object, or to no object, *do so*. What is stopping you?

Comment: @ispiro: It might help you (and everyone else!) if you post more code, so people can understand what the full intention is.  At the moment your question is nonsensical because it amounts to "I want to do this but I don't want to do it!"

Comment: @ispiro see if my images help you understand the concept of how references work.

Comment: Ugh. Let's just simplify this. @ispiro add "b = new myclass();
" to "disconnect" it at "--more lines of code" and the behavior will go away. It would be better if you understood WHY it wasn't working, but that is the short answer you seem to be looking for. Or better yet, get rid of the line a=b and the problem is also solved.

Comment: @JohnFx I think what he actually means by "disconnect" is to restore the "former" a.  Hopefully my drawings help explain that since words alone don't seem to suffice (to be fair it is a difficult concept for many people starting out)

Comment: @ispiro actually "To anyone who might read this because he has the same question, the core of the answer is: A field of a class-instance is not a pointer. Only the instance itself is." is not technically correct.  It is a pointer, but it's a different pointer.  My image was simplified because I didn't want to complicate it more than necessary, but technically speaking, 1 and 2 wouldn't be inside the circle, but the circle would have a line named `integer` pointing to 1 or 2.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your code:

```
myclass a = new myclass();
a.integer = 1;

myclass b = new myclass();
b.integer = 2;

a = b;

//here I need code to disconnect them

a.integer = 1;

Text = b.integer.ToString();
//I need b.integer to still be = 2
```

[image]

If you keep around a reference:

```
myclass a = new myclass();
a.integer = 1;

myclass b = new myclass();
b.integer = 2;

var c = a; //Keep the old a around
a = b;

//here I need code to disconnect them
a = c; //Restore it.

a.integer = 1;

Text = b.integer.ToString();
//It's still 2 now.
```

[image]

Variables are labels to the objects, not the objects themselves.  In your case, the original `a` no longer has a reference to it so even though it exists, there's no way to access it. (and it'll cease to exist whenever the garbage collector gets around to getting rid of it unless there are other references to it)

If it helps, think of it this way, when you say `a = b` or `a = new myclass()` you are moving the line where `a` is pointing.  When you say `a.integer = 1`, the `.` is kind of like saying follow the line `a` is pointing to, then change the destination.

Comment: @ispiro Sorry, edited it, I should be keeping `a` around not `b`.  Pics coming

Comment: @ispiro see the edit and check if the images help explain what's going on

Comment: This is the best answer here. Clearly a `$Temp` type variable is needed.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose you write "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue" on a piece of paper. That address refers to a house, in fact, the White House.

Suppose you write "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue" on a second piece of paper. That address refers to the *same* house as the first piece of paper.

There is absolutely nothing you can do to alter the fact that those two addresses refer to the same house. You can change one of the pieces of paper to say "123 Sesame Street", and then they no longer refer to the same house, but that isn't changing a fact about *The White House*, that's changing a fact about a piece of paper.

If you then paint the White House so that it is blue, you still haven't changed anything about either piece of paper; both now refer to a blue house.

Can you explain in more detail what it is that you're trying to do here? Your question is very confusing.

Comment: "You can change one of the pieces of paper to say "123 Sesame Street"." - that is precisely what I'm trying to do. How do I do that in c#?

Comment: instance2 = someotherHouseObject;  or possibly instance2 = new house("123 Sesame Street");

Comment: @ispiro: But they they are not referencing *the same object*. One of them is referencing President Obama's house and one of them is referencing Big Bird's nest. Both of them are referencing houses, but different houses.

Comment: @JohnFx: The statement of the question is "I want them referencing the same object".

Comment: Somehow I feel like I'm in an argument with my wife here, where logic does not apply and the ground rules change with each exchange.

Comment: @JohnFx: I'm not touching that one.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand better what you are saying based on your comments.

The answer is very very simple.

This code:

```
instance1 = instance2;
```

Does not link instance1 and instance2 in any way other than the fact that they point to the same thing. You can always re-point either variable (including "Nulling" them) without affecting the other. Setting either instance to null doesn't change the object it just makes it stop pointing at the object in memory.

In essence, the premise of the question is inaccurate. There is no problem here to solve.

**Key point to understand:** The variables instance1 and instance2 just store the location of an
   object in memory, not the actual object. If you wanted to manipulate the actual object you would use a method or property on that object, for example:

```
instance1.ChangeColor; // call the ChangeColor method on the object pointed to by instance1.
```

**Update:**

Assume a and b are index cards with the address of a mailbox that can hold a number. Here is a play-by-play of what your code is doing

```
//create a mailbox (call it X)  and write the address on index card A
myclass a = new myclass();  

//put the number 1 in the mailbox at the address written on index card A (currently x)
a.integer = 1;   //mailbox x now contains 1

//create ANOTHER mailbox (call it Y) and write the address on index card B
myclass b = new myclass(); 

//put the number 2 in the mailbox at the address written on index card B (currently Y) 
b.integer = 2;  //mailbox y now contains 2

// change the address on index card A to the address from card B (currently Y)
a = b;  //both cards now have the address of mailbox Y (which contains 2) written on them. 

// if you want a to go back to having the address of mailbox X, you are
// out of luck because you don't have it written down on any of your cards anymore.

//put the number 1 in the mailbox at the address pointed to on Card A (Currently Y)
a.integer = 1;  //mailbox Y now contains 1

//Set text to the number from the mailbox at the address on card B (currently Y)
Text = b.integer.ToString();
```

Comment: I like this answer, but should think it should qualify what is a "variable" and how it differs from an "object", etc.

Comment: "Key point to understand" - I know that. I want to change one _pointer_ without affecting the other.

Comment: Right, then just change it. It WON'T affect the other. That's what half a dozen people are trying to tell you.

Comment: @ispiro - I added a rundown of exactly what your code is doing. Hope this helps you understand.

Comment: @ispiro but when you say `a.integer = 1` you aren't changing the pointer, you are following the pointer and changing the value at the end of it.

Comment: @ispiro - It does because you left out the code to point a to something else. If you insert a line that sets a to anything but b, then changes to a will no longer affect b. Understand that A and B do NOT store the values 1 and 2, they store a link to a place in memory where those values are stored.

Comment: @Davy8 I thought I was changing the pointer to a new address and putting a ‘1’ there. _This_ is _the_ answer.

Comment: I think you are starting to see the light. Whenever you see a . after a variable name, the part to the right of the dot is manipulating/reading from the actual object being pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

Write a copy constructor for the class in question, and point one of your references to a new instance that was created via the copy constructor.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "copy constructor" in C#.

Comment: This is what I had in mind: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass instance1 = new MyClass();
MyClass instance2 = new MyClass();

instance1 = instance2;

instance1 = null; //does not affect instance2.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you want to do. Clearly, if you set `instance1 = null`, then the references won't be the same. Are you instead asking how to make a deep copy?

You probably want to look into the [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) interface. You have to write code that will copy the properties of one instance into the other.

Alternatively, you can overload the `=` operator. Or create a constructor that you can call:

```
MyClass instance2 = new MyClass(instance1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to clone your instance (create a replica of an instance).

For example, in your class:

```
public MyClass(MyClass copy)
{
    // ...copy all attributes, be careful with reference variables
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
instance1 = new MyClass(instance2);
```

They would both have the exact same attributes and properties (if you implemented your copy constructor correctly), but modifying one wouldn't affect the other.

Answer (score 0):

Can your class be a struct instead to cause it to be a value type?

```
public void Main()
{
    MyObj a = new MyObj{ integer= 1};
    MyObj b = a;

    Console.WriteLine(a.integer); //1
    Console.WriteLine(b.integer);//1

    b.integeter = 42;

    Console.WriteLine(a.integer);//1
    Console.WriteLine(b.integer);//42
}

public struct MyObj
{
    public int integer{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Don't put bullets in that gun. His shoes have enough holes already. =)

Comment: I need it as a value type at first.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that it is most helpful to think of fields and variables of a class type as holding "instance id's".  Some people think of them as pointers, but that's an implementation detail.  The essential thing to realize is that if Foo is a variable of class type Bar, the statement "Foo.Boz()" doesn't instruct the compiler to alter Foo in any way; it instructs the compiler to look up the object referred to by the instance id stored in Foo (the object must be of type Bar), and run the Boz method on that object.  Very few operations can be done an instance id itself, rather than on the object referred to thereby:

1. An instance id can be copied from one variable or field to another.

   An instance id can be passed by value to a method or property

   An instance id can be passed by reference to a method or property

   An instance id can be compared with another (without looking at the objects referred to the id's--just the id's themselves)

If Biff and Baff are identical instance id's, actions done to the object referred to by Biff will affect the object referred to by Baff, since they're the same object (but such actions won't actually affect Biff and Baff themselves, which will still hold the same instance id's as before).  If one wants Biff to refer to an object which is similar to the one referred to by Baff, but with some difference, then one must create a new object similar to the one referred to by Biff and Baff, store into Biff the id of that new object, and then modify that object so it differs in the desired way from the one pointed to by Baff.

Note, by the way, that in addition to supporting class types, .net also supports value types (e.g. primitives like Integer or Double, as well as structures).  Unlike class types, variables and fields of value types are disjoint; changing one will not affect any other.  In many cases value types make it easier to isolate data dependencies.  It is important to note, however, that while it is useful to be able to make changes to one value-type variable or field without affecting any other, one must, when changing part of a value-type entity (e.g. one field in a structure), be aware that in certain cases, .net will silently make a copy of a value-type entity and then operate on the copy.