# Strip Class of functions and return generic Object with data only

Tags: c#

Say I have a class of type Item, and that class have property, functions, everything.  I would like to make it into a generic Object with only the instance data left.  I would like to remove all function, static or not.  How would I do this?

Some code example:

```
Item testItem = new Item();
testItem.fieldA = "aaaa";
testItem.functionB("B");

// strip data
Object strippedItem = strip(testItem);

// only data is left
string a = strippedItem.fieldA;  // aaaa
strippedItem.functionB("B") // error, functionB does not exist.
```

I guess to some degree, this question is asking how do I automatically create struct from class without having to declare them.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Are you asking to modify your source code?

Comment: No, I would like to do this in memory, I will add some example.

Comment: I'm not sure I truly understand your question, but would assigning to an `object` be enough?

Comment: If you cast something to object, you won't be able to use any of the methods and such... But if you want some kind of DTO, you should probably design a specific class for that. You could even make an anonymous type, if it's just data...

Comment: Are you asking for shallow copy? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066429/shallow-copy-or-deep-copy

Comment: Can you give a little detail about *why* you want to do this?  It's kind of an odd scenario for a typed language to want to do this.

Comment: For serialization.  But the code I am using is crashing on my static function in my class, so I want to strip my class of functions and leave only data left, which will not cause any problem in the serialization process.  And before you ask, no, I can't edit the serialization code, and I have to work around the error.

Comment: There is no remotely sane way to do that.  You could use `ILGenerator` to duplicate the class.

Comment: lol, alright fine, I'll try something else.

Comment: I found a way to do this!  Don't know if you guys will think it's "sane" or not but at least it works!  I basically Serialize then Deserialize to a Object!  Which will strip my class of any functions and leave just the data behind!!  I will post answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround to do exactly this (warning:  this solution might be insane):

```
           Item test = new Item();
           JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
           string jsonStr = jsonSerializer.Serialize(test);
           Object strippedItem = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Object>(jsonStr);
```

Comment: That just returns a dictionary with all of your properties.

Comment: I see, I guess that is what I wanted to do, I just didn't know how to ask.  Is there any more efficient way to do this?