# Updating One Object Updates the Other somehow

Tags: c#, guid

I have two objects, yet when i update one, the other item with the same GUID gets updated as well even though i am trying to apply a new GUID so that i can separate them out.

```
var completedSecond = model.CompletedTransfers.First();
var transferedTransfers = model.TransferedTransfers.First();

if (transferedTransfers.Count != 0) {
    transferedTransfers.RowId = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

When i run this code, the two items have the same GUID, yet when i update the second one to have a new GUID, the first object also gets that new GUID. How is this possible?

Comment: You don't have 2 objects but 2 references to the same object in memory

Comment: is it possible to split them out?

Comment: or to recreate one object into another with a different GUID?

Comment: use different GUID

Comment: If the class implements [ICloneable.Clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) is is pretty easy to splilt them, otherwise we'd need to look at how the objects are constructed (i.e. you'll need to provide more code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have 2 objects but 2 references to the same object in memory. In C# classes are reference types meaning that your `completedSecond` is referencing an object in memory, that in this case is the same as the object `transferedTransfers` is referenceing to.

In order to get 2 different object you need to instantiate a new object

1. By implementing the [`ICloneable` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx)

   ```
   public class MyClass : ICloneable
   {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }

       public object Clone()
       {
           return new MyClass { Id = Id };
       }
   }
   ```
2. Another way is to have a [copy constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116(v=vs.100).aspx):

   ```
   public class MyClass
   {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }

       public MyClass() { }

       public MyClass(MyClass other)
       {
           Id = other.Id;
       }
   }
   ```

Read this for the differences between the two ways: [Copy constructor versus Clone()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3345389/6400526)

In addition, when talking about coping of objects you have what is called deep-copy and shallow-copy. More on these you can find here:

- [Shallow copy or Deep copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18066429/6400526)
- [Object.MemberwiseClone Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so what does the actual instantiation look like since you are instantiating something from something else (clone)?

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the model.TransferedTransfers object is passed by reference, not by value. the variable completedSecond and transferedTransfers both points to model.CompletedTransfers. Also be aware of naming smells (transferedTranfers)