# C++ Heap Corruption Detected error occurred

Tags: c++, constructor

When I tried to operate my code, it's executed well except Debug Error popping out. Error message is here.

[image]

And my Full Code is here.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class String {
public :
    String() { 
        strData = NULL; 
        len = 0;
        cout << "constructor executed !" << endl;
    }

    String(const char *str){
        len = strlen(str);
        strData = new char[len+1];
        strcpy_s(strData, sizeof(str), str);

        cout << sizeof(str) << endl;
        cout << sizeof(len) << endl;
        cout << sizeof(strData) << endl;
        cout << strData << endl;
    }
    ~String() {
        delete[] strData; //Fails here!
    }
    char* GetStrData() const{ 
        return strData;
    }
    int GetLen() const {
        return len;
    }
private : 
    char* strData; 
    int len;
};

int main() {
    String str; 
    str = String("Hi");
}
```

and result is here

[image]

I presumed this message is because of size of strData but I don't know exactly.

I need help from you guys. thanks.

Comment: You will want to look up the rule of three/five/zero: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: I'm also unsure whether you really want to output *sizeof* len, and *sizeof* strdata.

Comment: `strcpy_s(strData, sizeof(str), str)` -> `strcpy(strData, str);`. You know that `strData` point to a bcorrectly allocated buffer. And anyway it should have been `strcpy_s(strData, len+1, str);`. All your usage of `sizeof` in this code is pretty pointless.

Comment: @Jabberwocky there's also the little matter of the double-delete caused by the use of the implicit copy assignment on a owning raw pointer...

Comment: Although I changed `strcpy_s(strData, sizeof(str), str)` -> `strcpy_s(strData, len+1, str);` Triggered a breakpoint exception is still on `delete[] strData`. (But popup error msg is gone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

`str = String("Hi");`

is (very roughly) the equivalent of:

```
String tmp("hi")
str.strData = tmp.strData;
str.len = tmp.len;
```

So when both `tmp` and `str` get deleted, you end up calling `delete` twice on the same address.

You need to write a custom `operator=()` method in your `String` class to handle that.

Once you've opened that pandora's box, you should be crossing your Ts and dotting your Is correctly. This is known as the rule of 0/3/5. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) question for details:

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

The `str = String("Hi");` statement invokes the default [copy-assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) operator (implicitly-declared) special member function of your class. While destruction (two objects are being created in your program), the same memory will be destroyed twice because two objects in your program points to the same memory and they both consider themselves as the owner of the memory.

**Long Answer:**

Since, you haven't defined the copy-assignment operator and compiler generated version would copy the pointers (`shallow copy`) to the other class.

> If no user-defined copy assignment operators are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare one as an inline public member of the class.

The implicity-declared copy-assignment operator generated by compiler would look like:

```
String& operator=(const String& other)
{
    strData = other.strData;
    len = other.len;
    return *this;
}
```

So, the implicitly-declared copy-assignment operator member function does the [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066429/shallow-copy-or-deep-copy/18066487) and hence, it just copy the pointer's (not their value). Before the end of `str = String("Hi");` statement, you will be having two `String` objects (`str` object and temporary object created by `String("Hi")`)  and their `strData` will be pointing to the same character array. When the temporary generated by `String("Hi")` will be destroyed, it will free the memory and when `str` object will be destroyed, it will also try to free/delete the same memory and hence, you are getting your `heap` corrupted.

Learn about [copy-and-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) idiom. Try this:

```
String& operator=(String other)
{
    swap(other, *this);
    return *this;
}

void swap(String& first, String& second)
{
    std::swap(first.strData, second.strData);
    std::swap(first.len, second.len);
}
```

Try the program below. I have commented out the `copy-assignment` operator to demonstrate a pointer getting destroyed twice.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

class String {
public :
    String(void): strData(nullptr), len(0)
    { 
        std::cout << "constructor executed !" << std::endl;
    }

    String(const char *str)
    {

        len = strlen(str);
        strData = new char[len + 1];
        std::copy(str, str + len + 1, strData);
        std::cout << "Constructing memory: " << strData << std::endl;
        std::cout << sizeof(str) << std::endl;
        std::cout << sizeof(len) << std::endl;
        std::cout << sizeof(strData) << std::endl;
        std::cout << strData << std::endl;
    }

 //    String& operator=(String other)
    // {
    //  swap(other, *this);
    //  return *this;
    // }

    ~String()
    {
        if (strData == nullptr)
            return;

        std::cout << "Destroying memory: " << (void *)strData << std::endl;
        delete[] strData; //Fails here!
    }

    char* GetStrData(void) const
    { 
        return strData;
    }

    int GetLen(void) const
    {
        return len;
    }

    void swap(String& first, String& second)
    {
        std::swap(first.strData, second.strData);
        std::swap(first.len, second.len);
    }

private : 
    char* strData; 
    int len;
};

int main() 
{
    String str; 
    str = String("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
constructor executed !
Constructing memory: Hi
8
4
8
Hi
Destroying memory: 0x7fffc5628080
Destroying memory: 0x7fffc5628080
```

Comment: See my complete answer now, it prints now where was the problem, i.e., showing how the same memory was getting destroyed twice.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, the line `strcpy_s(strData, sizeof(str), str);` is problematic. The second parameter is supposed to be the size of the destination buffe `len + 1` as you used in the `new` operator. Remember `sizeof(strData)` is the size of the pointer, it's always 8 bytes for 64bit machines or 4 bytes in 32bit machines. It is not the length of the string.