# C# filter a list that is in another list

Tags: c#, linq

In the example below, I have a list of people who have many pets. Is there a way to return the pets with an age that `is > than 5`, but exclude the other pets that person owns where the age is `NOT > 5 years`

Example: If a person has 2 pets one is 6 years, the other is 2 years, then return that person and the 6-year-old pet, and EXCLUDE the 2-year-old pet from the list.

```
class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
class Person
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Pet[] Pets { get; set; }
}

public static void AllEx2()
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>
        { new Person { LastName = "Haas",
                       Pets = new Pet[] { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=10 },
                                          new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=14 },
                                          new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=6 }}},
          new Person { LastName = "Fakhouri",
                       Pets = new Pet[] { new Pet { Name = "Snowball", Age = 1}}},
          new Person { LastName = "Antebi",
                       Pets = new Pet[] { new Pet { Name = "Belle", Age = 8} }},
          new Person { LastName = "Philips",
                       Pets = new Pet[] { new Pet { Name = "Sweetie", Age = 2},
                                          new Pet { Name = "Rover", Age = 13}} }
        };

    people.ForEach(person=>
        {

            person.Pets.Where(pet => pet.Age > 5);
        });
}
```

Comment: "and modify the people list to not return pets that are NOT > 5 years" This doesn't make sense. The people list has _people_, not pets. Do you want to remove the _people_ that has at least one pet that is not > 5 years?

Comment: If a person has a pet that is greater than 5, return that person and that pet, but exclude the other pets that person owns that are less than 5 years

Comment: If a person only has pets that are not greater than 5 years old, do you want to include that person? In any case, you are still saying things like "exclude the 2-year-old pet from the list". *The list does not contain pets!* The `Pets` property of each `Person` object in the list contains pets. So to remove pets, you need to set that property, which means modifying the `Person` object. Or, you can create a copy of the `Person` objects, with `Pets` set to the filtered pets. Which one do you want?

Comment: If a person only has pets that are not greater than 5 years old, I do not want to include that person.

modifying the Person object u suggest having a method in the person object that can filter by age?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might solve your problem. Try something like this

```
class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
class Person
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Pet[] Pets { get; set; }
}

public static void AllEx2()
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>
        { new Person { LastName = "Haas",
                       Pets = new Pet[] { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=10 },
                                          new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=14 },
                                          new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=6 }}},
          new Person { LastName = "Fakhouri",
                       Pets = new Pet[] { new Pet { Name = "Snowball", Age = 1}}},
          new Person { LastName = "Antebi",
                       Pets = new Pet[] { new Pet { Name = "Belle", Age = 8} }},
          new Person { LastName = "Philips",
                       Pets = new Pet[] { new Pet { Name = "Sweetie", Age = 2},
                                          new Pet { Name = "Rover", Age = 13}} }
        };

    people.ForEach(person=>
        {
            // create an array with the result and reassign it to the respt array
           var pets = person.Pets.Where(pet => pet.Age > 5).ToArray();
           person.Pets = pets;
        });
}
```

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066429/shallow-copy-or-deep-copy)  may be the reason. Please go through it. You will get an idea why this doesn't filter the values in your loop

Answer (score 0):

You either need to re-assign the where clause back to person.Pets (would permanently lose/remove any <= 5 pets though):

```
person.Pets = person.Pets.Where(pet => pet.Age > 5);
```

Store it locally:

```
var pets = person.Pets.Where(pet => pet.Age > 5);
```

And then iterate the local variable:

```
foreach(var p in pets)
```

Or foreach it inline instead:

```
foreach(var p in person.Pets.Where(pet => pet.Age > 5))
```

Comment: The problem is that on my real model the Pets is private so I cant reassign it outside the class

Answer (score 0):

I would change the foreach section to:

```
people.ForEach(person=>
{
    // Get all pets for this person that are older than 5
    IEnumerable<Pet> pets = person.Pets.Where(pet => pet.Age > 5);

    // If this person has any
    if(pets.Count() != 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person.LastName);
        foreach(var p in pets)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }
    }
        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function do do the `predicate` part of a `Where` linq query you can resuse this for both filtering the `Person` objects and also getting the required list of pets

```
Func<Pet,bool> petsOver5 = (Pet p) => p.Age > 5;
```

and then

```
var peopleWithPetsOver5 = people.Where(p => p.Pets.Any(petsOver5));
foreach(var person in peopleWithPetsOver5)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Here are {person.LastName}'s pets over 5:");
    foreach(var pet in person.Pets.Where(petsOver5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{pet.Name} who is age {pet.Age}");
    }
}
```

Live example: https://rextester.com/WUVVE89613